# How to make Ajax Async calls within a Flask python app running with Nginx & gunicorn

Tags: python, docker, nginx, flask, gunicorn

I'm running a flask python app, within which I make some Ajax calls.
Running it using the Flask development server works fine, the calls run in the background and I can continue using the app.

When moving to a gunicorn and Nginx reverse proxy setup the app seems to wait for that Ajax call to be processed (often ending up in a timeout). Why is that? Does this have something to do with multithreading? I'm new to gunicorn/nginx. Thanks for the help

The setup is pretty much the same as described here: https://testdriven.io/blog/dockerizing-flask-with-postgres-gunicorn-and-nginx/#docker

The nginx config:

```
upstream app {
    server web:5000;
}

server {

    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://app;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location /static/ {
        alias /home/app/web/project/static/;
    }

    location /media/ {
        alias /home/app/web/project/media/;
    }

}
```

docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  web:
    container_name: app
    restart: always
    build:
      context: ./services/web
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod
    expose:
      - 5005
    env_file: 
      - ./.env.prod
    command: gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:5005 manage:app
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/home/hello_flask/web/app/static
      - media_volume:/home/hello_flask/web/app/media
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    container_name: app_prod_db
    restart: always
    image: postgres:13-alpine
    volumes:
      - postgres_data_prod:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    env_file:
      - ./.env.prod.db
      
  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    restart: always
    build: ./services/nginx
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/home/app/web/app/static
      - media_volume:/home/app/web/app/start/media
    image: "nginx:latest"
    ports:
      - "5000:80"
    depends_on: 
      - web

volumes:
  postgres_data_prod:
  static_volume:
  media_volume:
```

Don't think that Ajax call is an issue but just in case here it is:

```
$("#load_account").on('submit', function(event) {

    $.ajax({
        data : {
            vmpro : $('#accountInput').val()
        },
        type : 'POST',
        url : '/account/load_account'
    })
    .done(function(data) {

        if (data.error) {
            $('#errorAlert_accountvmproInput').text(data.error).show();
            $('#successAlert_accountInput').hide();
        }
        else {
            $('#successAlert_accountInput').text(data.overview).show();
            $('#errorAlert_accountInput').hide();
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solved:**

gunicorn was running 1 single worker and of the default sync class.
Increasing the number of workers to 4 solved the problem.

However I actually opted to use gevent class workers in the end.
My updated docker-compose yml includes:

```
command: gunicorn -k gevent -w 2 --bind 0.0.0.0:5005 manage:app
```

Detailed in gunicorn documentation [HERE](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/run.html)